# Is the back end of magento down?

Tags: category

Nothing will save or upload in the back end. is magento down? i cant create new categories or add or remove existing ones and the products within.

Comment: Try deploying your static content and check again

Comment: Send some screenshots if you can

Comment: run magento cli cmds

Comment: There are the serveral reason for `cant create new categories or add or remove existing ones and the products ` . that Might your server configuration and coding issue and datdabase issue many more. Best idea to  check the error a at system.log or exception.log at magento `var/log` folder of magento application